# Bash command to lock the screen in Unity

Tags: 12.04, unity, bash, command-line

I am in need to lock my screen with a bash command. The commands below
will provide a blank screen, however the desktop is brought back without a password prompt. Is there a better way to do this? Also, is there a setting to offer a password prompt on hibernation resume?

!
`gnome-screensaver-command --lock
gnome-screensaver-command -l`

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  Are you looking to add a Unity icon, to lock-screen? (I've already done that.)  Do you also want a (graphic) screensaver, and are using **Gnome screensaver**?

Comment: Opps, it is Ubuntu 12.04 and Unity. Both commands work, and I have the "password lock" "on" with the box checked for "Require my password when waking from suspend" in the settings. It still does not prompt me for a password. Also, this is a brand new installation.

Comment: Have you run **Ubuntu** updates yet?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is embarrassing but I found out why the password prompt is not working. 
These commands need to be run as user who owns the Unity session. My script is ran as user root. The `gnome-screensaver-command -l` command works now, but the pm-suspend still requires root privileges. So I will need to have a work around for that.

Answer (score 1):

When I run `gnome-screensaver-command --lock`, it prompts me for a password.

If you're using Precise, try going to System Settings > Brightness and Lock > and then see if the settings there help.  I have lock on and have it set to prompt for a password after suspend, both of which seem to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround if you still need it:

```
su <user> -c 'export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-screensaver-command -l'
```